# How to prove the Cardinal Number.

Tags: linear-algebra

Assume that $A$ and $B$ are finte sets and  $card(A)=n$ and $card(B)=m$, 
we will show that $card(A^B)=m^n$.

Pleas, hint me to prove this, i try to prove by induction(fiexd set$B$) but i can't use induction hypothesis, or can create a bijection $f:A^B\to ? $

Thank for give me .

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're asking. Are $A$ and $B$ supposed to be finite sets? Do you mean to show that $card(A^B) = n^m$?

Comment: Hint: Try induction on the cardinality of $B$, with the induction hypothesis "for all finite sets $A$, $card(A^B) = card(A)^{card(B)}$. Use the fact that $n^{m+1} = n*n^m$.

Answer (score 2):

You can create the following bijection: first, order the elements of $B$ as, say, $B=\{b_1,\dots,b_m\}$. Then any element of $A^B$, which is a map $p$ from $B$ to $A$, is determined by giving all the images of the elements of $B$.

Define
$f: A^B \to A^m$ 
by $f(p)=(p(b_1),\dots,p(b_m))$. It is a bijection.

Now, the cardinal of the product $A^m$ is $n^m$.